# RewriteRule match anything

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm creating a function to report all 404 errors that happen on my site so I can redirect any what need doing, I'm also logging where the user was before (if possible). Some of the URL's are really long and strange, e.g.

`news/read/gbbasketball+++++++++++++++Result:+chosen+nickname+%22hisapriepay%22;+success;`

I need to pass all that to my inspecting code to view the details, so I was going to encode the url and pass it as a parameters to my controller.

`news%2Fread%2Fgbbasketball%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2BResult%3A%2Bchosen%2Bnickname%2B%2522hisapriepay%2522%3B%2Bsuccess%3B`

I need a RewriteRule to match any character and pass it. This is what I've got but it doesn't seem to work.

`RewriteRule     ^developer/brokenLinks/inspect/(.*)$ /?module=developer&controller=brokenLinks&action=inspect&params=$1   [NC,L]`

From what I've read (.*) should match any character, but when I load the URL

`http://cms.mywebsite.com/developer/brokenLinks/inspect/news%2Fread%2Fgbbasketball%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2B%2BResult%3A%2Bchosen%2Bnickname%2B%2522hisapriepay%2522%3B%2Bsuccess%3B`

I just get a white screen with a Not Found error display, not my sites custom 404 error, it looks like the default one.

What can I do to get the URL to match the pattern? Or would there be a better way to do it? The URL's don't have a unique I'd assigned to them, I could rewrite the whole logging code to assign one but I'd rather not go through and redo all that id I don't need to.

EDIT: See my answer

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using urlencode I changed it to base64_encode/decode to pass it through the URL, and doing that my rule above works fine.